# XSLT 2 chain replaces?

Tags: xml, xslt, replace

I need to do a series of replacements in a XSLT 2 stylesheet.  For example I need to replace all occurrences of “aaa” with “bbb”, and all “ccc” with “ddd”.  In terms of normal `replace` calls, I should have

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(replace(text(), 'aaa', 'bbb'), 'ccc', 'ddd')"/>
```

However, the situation is that I have hundreds of such replacement pairs, and for that I need a super long `select` attribute.  I guess I can generate the select string with, for example, a Python script, but it'll be ugly.  Is there a XSLT thing maybe like

```
<xsl:replace from="aaa" to="bbb"/>
<xsl:replace from="ccc" to="ddd"/>
…
```

so that the XSLT is more readable and maintainable (and machine-manipulatable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create a function that can replace each term

**XSLT 2.0**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:funct="http://something"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="funct:textreplace($replaces/replaces/rep, .)"/>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:param name="replaces">
        <replaces>
            <rep from="aaa" to="bbb"/>
            <rep from="ccc" to="ddd"/>
        </replaces>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:function name="funct:textreplace" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="reps" as="element(rep)*"/>
        <xsl:param name="text" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not($reps)">
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="funct:textreplace($reps[position() gt 1], replace($text, $reps[1]/@from, $reps[1]/@to))"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```